# Diseño de tipo Split-plot

Tags: r, rstudio

Tengo una pequeña duda. El caso es que estoy intentando analizar el efecto de unos factores en mi variable "Peso seco". El experimento sigue un diseño Split-plot, por lo que las variables están anidadas: Hongo está dentro de Tratamiento y Tratamiento está dentro de Línea. Además Línea es un factor aleatorio o de bloque.

He hecho el análisis con la función aov() y el resultado es el mismo que el que obtuve con el SPSS, por lo que es correcto. He utilizado el siguiente código:

`AOV <- aov(pesoSeco ~ Tratamiento * Hongo + Error(linea/Tratamiento), data=Tritordeum, na.action = na.exclude)`

El caso es que me gustaría hacer el análisis con la función lme() porque me resulta más útil para luego hacer otras cosas, pero cuando utilizo la función lme() el resultado que me sale es distinto del anterior. Este es el código que he puesto:

`modelo <- lme(pesoSeco ~ Tratamiento + Hongo + Tratamiento:Hongo, random=~1|linea/Tratamiento, data = Tritordeum, method = "ML", na.action = na.omit)`

¿Alguien sabe qué es lo que estoy escribiendo mal? ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que me salga con lme() el mismo resultado que me salió con aov()? Muchas gracias, un saludo.

Comment: Bienvenida María! ¿Podrías incluir el output de `aov()` y `lme`? Serviría para saber qué es lo diferente, si es el número de parámetros que estima el modelo, los coeficientes o los errores que estima. A priori: si el número de parámetros (coef y ordenadas al orígen) es diferente es porque la especificación del modelo es diferente. Si los coeficientes son los mismos pero los errores no, entonces podría ser pq `lme` los calcula por máxima verosimilitud y `aov()` que depende de `lm()` no.

Answer (score 0):

La estimación con lme debe hacerse con el método "REML", no con "ML", REML corrige el sesgo en la estimación de los componentes de la varianza ([dejo un enlace aquí](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48671/what-is-restricted-maximum-likelihood-and-when-should-it-be-used)). Prueba con REML